# Rspec sample specs for learning purpose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to learn behavior driven development with rails and I need some references like searhable api for rspec and some example code. Anyone can direct me to some online resources?

Comment: This post http://www.arailsdemo.com/posts/37 and most of the posts after that will have a lot of RSpec examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official documentation (written as Cucumber features): http://relishapp.com/rspec

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few to start with:

[rspec documentation](http://rspec.info/documentation/)

[a list of resources](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=8253)

Comment: please note: I googled "rspec examples tutorial" and got these links plus a ton of others...